# Need the novel title: small blue creatures, UBI

Tags: story-identification

Need the title of this book: Earth future with Universal Basic Income. Much routine labor done by small blue genetically modified creatures. Possibly written by a biochemist or similar scientist.

Any ideas?

Edit: book was in English, read in paperback around late 90s / early 00s, published within a decade or so of that time I think. Pretty sure an American author. I remember nothing of the plot. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide more information on this? How long since you read this, language you read it in, or anything else from [this list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: "Smurfs - the Enslavement"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble We need to know our goals before we begin. How completely must you crush their culture to make them stop saying "smurfy"?